# How can I improve my question about Xcode?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Here's my question I posted almost a month ago and still don't see *any* activity there: [Xcode refuses to build one of my OpenCL projects but builds another one successfully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250299/failing-to-work-with-cl-hpp-on-mac-os). The point is, the problem *is still there* and I'm unable to solve it. I'm just stuck and cannot move on. I can provide any information needed, anything that can help to answer.

What's wrong with it? Is it on-topic? Or maybe it belongs to another SE site?

Comment: Your question definitely looks on-topic. You might want to add a bounty to it to attract more attention.

Comment: I've just added a bounty and still looking for some advice on how to improve this question.

Comment: That is one of the most reasonably scooped questions I've seen in quite a while, but a better title may help you with the visibility issue. BTW, I'm deeply sorry that you have to use Xcode.

Comment: @Braiam, what's wrong with Xcode? Are there any other good _free_ C++ IDEs for Mac OS?

Comment: Have you tried [emacs](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsForMacOS#toc1)?

Comment: @Braiam, yes already, but I think Xcode is better (maybe I'm extremely wrong :) but I'm used to it)

Comment: This isn't always a good idea, but in your case I think it might be helpful to post your Xcode project somewhere so people can download and try it out for themselves.

Comment: @ForceBru, have you tried considering creating a sample project for the same? Is the error still coming from that sample as well?

Comment: @jtbandes, should I post the _whole_ project or just the source code? If you're looking for the source, [here it is](https://github.com/ForceBru/Matrix) (the first project only, which works well). I can also post the second one on GitHub in a few hours as well

Comment: @Hemang, not yet. Although I've checked the settings manually and they were the same. Just a note: at first, these projects weren't using OpenCL and worked fine, but when I added OpenCL support, the second one started to fail

Comment: @ForceBru I'd go for the whole project, as that is the fastest way other people can get to fiddle around on it. Also, with only the broken project, people can probably find the bug, with only the working one though, that's rather unlikely.

Answer (score 3):

You should make your question as distinct as possible - outline the specifics, be as absolute as possible with working out your question and resort to underlining your points - by doing so you:
work out significant issues within the codes
secondly: you can then rework the other questions that have been tagged before you ask your own.